# Returning a ListView from a Function C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, list, listview

I have a XML that stores multiple Transactions. Now i want to parse that into a ListView and return the ListView.

And here is the function that Parses the XML and returns the ListView

```
    public ListView ReadPaths()
    {
        try
        {
            ListView oList = new ListView();

            XmlDocument oXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
            oXMLDoc.Load("Buchungen.xml");
            XmlNodeList oTransactions = oXMLDoc.SelectNodes("Buchungen/Buchung");

            foreach(XmlNode oTransaction in oTransactions)
            {
                ListViewItem oItem = new ListViewItem();
                if (oTransaction.Attributes["positive"].Value == "true")
                    oItem.ImageIndex = 0;
                else
                    oItem.ImageIndex = 1;

                oItem.SubItems.Add(oTransaction.Attributes["description"].Value);
                oItem.SubItems.Add(oTransaction.Attributes["date"].Value);
                oItem.SubItems.Add(oTransaction.Attributes["amount"].Value);

                oList.Items.Add(oItem);
            }

            return oList;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim lesen der Daten: " + ex.Message, "Fehler!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The ListView that I assign this source to, has a count that is greater than zero - which is expected.

```
        XMLHandler oXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
        lstGeldEintraege = oXMLHandler.ReadPaths();
        lstGeldEintraege.Refresh();
```

After ^this call, my ListView won´t do anything. If I try to add an Element to that ListView afterwards, it won´t react. The ListView.Items.Count is still +1 as expected but i am not able to review values of the subItems for some Reason. It also deserializes the Items that I add, but it never displays one. If i delete the ReadPaths() call, my Items show up properly. Whats that behaviour about and what could help fixing it?

Comment: If you dislike, i would love to know why. A comment would help improving my questions ;)

Comment: I am not really sure but if you do this all events linked to lstGeldEintraege will be lost as you create a new ListView.

Comment: So i should return an array of items and assign it to the listview?

Comment: Or pass the ListView to your function... clear the items and then repopulate it.

Comment: Give me a second, i will try a workaround to see if thats the reason

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

It seems like user2888973 was right. All linked Elements are deleted when assigning the ListView. I just had to use a reference as a Parameter and it worked! :)